# Character literal for vertical tab?

Tags: scala

How can I write a character literal for a vertical tab ('\v', ASCII 11) in Scala?

`'\v'` doesn't work. (invalid escape character)
`'\11'` should be it, but...

```
scala> '\11'.toInt
res13: Int = 9
```

But 9 is the ASCII code for a normal tab('\t'). What is going on there?

EDIT: This works and produces the right character, but I'd still like to know the syntax for a literal.

```
val c:Char = 11
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `'\13'`. It's in octal.

For more information see [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

> 1.3.4 Character Literals
>
> Syntax:
>
> characterLiteral ::= ‘\’’ printableChar ‘\’’ | ‘\’’ charEscapeSeq ‘\’’
>
> A character literal is a single character enclosed in quotes. The
>   character is either a printable unicode character or is described by
>   an escape sequence (§1.3.6).
>
> Example 1.3.4 Here are some character
>   literals: ’a’ ’\u0041’ ’\n’ ’\t’ Note that ‘\u000A’ is not a valid
>   character literal because Unicode conversion is done before literal
>   parsing and the Unicode character \u000A (line feed) is not a
>   printable character. One can use instead the escape sequence ‘\n’ or
>   the octal escape ‘\12’ (§1.3.6).

Comment: yep, just noticed this myself...great. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Actually, a char lit will take anything. You can use `val c: Char = '^K'`, as well as `'\u000A'`.